# Create a square using index coordinates (x,y,z) and size of a one side

Tags: c++, object, opengl

In my Open GL C++ program I've created a circle using index x,y,z coordinates and radius. And I want to create a square with the size of 2r and using that coordinates. Can somebody explain me how to create square using r, x, y, z. Square's one side should equal to 2r

From below code I can calculate x and y coordinates of the square but how do I get the z coordinates?

```
void drawSquare(double x1, double y1, double sidelength)
{
    double halfside = sidelength / 2;

    glColor3d(0,0,0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glVertex2d(x1 + halfside, y1 + halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 + halfside, y1 - halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 - halfside, y1 - halfside);
    glVertex2d(x1 - halfside, y1 + halfside);

    glEnd();
}
```

This square is rotating as well therefore cannot use index z value of the circle as well.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework. What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163188/openglc-draw-square I think I found the answer from this post

Comment: @redFIVE I can create square using x and y coordinates but how do I create if there is z axis as well?

Comment: Using the same way